# Adding new key value pair to existing array didn't work in php

Tags: php

I have an associative array in which i want to add a new key-value pair to the existing .
Here is my code

```
foreach($result['apiAvailableBuses'] as $value){
     if(strpos($value['fare'], ",")!== false){ 
       $fare=substr($value['fare'], 0, strpos($value['fare'], ","))." +";
     }
  else{ 
     $fare=$value['fare']."/-";
  }
   //add new key
   $result['apiAvailableBuses'][]['actualFare']=$fare;


}
```

But the 
`print_r($result['apiAvailableBuses']['actualFare'])` gives undefined error.

Comment: I don't see `$fare` defined, do you ?

Comment: Could you show us your full code? Is that `[]` intentional or did you miss it out in your `print_r`.

Comment: `print_r($result['apiAvailableBuses']['actualFare'])` show undefined because it's undefined, your defining `$result['apiAvailableBuses'][0]['actualFare']`

Comment: @Script updated my question

Comment: @Daan ok how can i add new key value to `$result['apiAvailableBuses']` this array?

Comment: Change `$result['apiAvailableBuses'][]['actualFare']` in `$result['apiAvailableBuses']['actualFare']`

Comment: But it print only one value

Comment: Yes I know. You say “But the  `print_r($result['apiAvailableBuses']['actualFare']`)”

Comment: I need a new key -value pair in every key of `($result['apiAvailableBuses']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not clear: you want an array with all values (as per `foreach`suggests) or one only value (as per `$result['apiAvailableBuses']['actualFare']` suggests)?

If you want an array with all the values, write in this way:

```
foreach( $result['apiAvailableBuses'] as $key => $value )
{
    if( strpos( $value['fare'], "," ) !== false )
    { 
        $fare = substr( $value['fare'], 0, strpos( $value['fare'], "," ) )." +";
    }
    else
    { 
        $fare = $value['fare'] . "/-";
    }
    // add new key
    $result['apiAvailableBuses'][$key]['actualFare'] = $fare;
}
```

In this way you will add `$fare` to same key of current `$result` element. Otherwise, you will append a new `$result` element.

Comment: I need the entire array with a new key `actualFare` and its value